# Ansible task for run Docker container from private registry

Tags: ansible, docker-registry

I have a private Docker registry runnning in `172.20.20.20` in port `5000`. And I have pushed the image `pruebasjeje` to it.

Now, I need to pull and run the image using Ansible task:

```
   - name: run container
     docker:
       registry: 172.20.20.20:5000
       insecure_registry: true
       image: pruebasjeje
       state: reloaded
       pull: always
       ports:
        - "8080:8080"
```

But when I execute it, I get this error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "changes":
>   ["{\"status\":\"Pulling repository
>   docker.io/library/pruebasjeje\"}\r\n",
>   "{\"errorDetail\":{\"message\":\"Error: image
>   library/pruebasjeje:latest not found\"},\"error\":\"Error: image
>   library/pruebasjeje:latest not found\"}\r\n"], "failed": true, "msg":
>   "Unrecognized status from pull.", "status": ""}

It seems that is looking for the image in docker.io. How should I write my task in order to do what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: The Ansible `docker` module is [deprecated](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html#id1) in favor of `docker_container` and `docker_image` modules

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if it is how it should be done, but this is how I do it:

```
   - name: run container
     docker:
       insecure_registry: true
       image: 172.20.20.20:5000/pruebasjeje
       state: reloaded
       pull: always
       ports:
        - "8080:8080"
```

I just started with Docker myself. Here are the tasks I have for setting up Docker on my target host (CentOS 7):

```
- name: Install epel repo
  yum:
    name: "http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}/{{ ansible_userspace_architecture }}{{ '/' if ansible_distribution_major_version < '7' else '/e/' }}epel-release-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}-5.noarch.rpm"
    state: present
  become: yes

- name: Install Docker
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
    enablerepo: epel
  with_items:
    - device-mapper
    - docker-engine
    - python-pip
  become: yes

- name: Install docker-py
  pip:
    name: docker-py
  become: yes

- name: Add registry cert
  copy:
    src: registry.crt
    dest: /etc/docker/certs.d/{{ docker_registry_host }}/ca.crt
  become: yes

- name: Allow access to insecure registry
  lineinfile:
    dest: /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
    regexp: ^ExecStart=
    line: ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --insecure-registry {{ docker_registry_host }}:5000
  become: yes

- name: Start Docker service
  service:
    name: docker
    state: started
    enabled: yes
  become: yes
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I get a new error: `APIError(HTTPError(u'500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+unix://var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/images/create?tag=latest&fromImage=172.20.34.112%3A5000%2Fpruebasjeje',),)"` Can you help me?

Comment: Hm, no idea what that means. I just started looking into Docker a few days ago. I added the tasks I use to install Docker itself to my answer. That's all I did to setup Docker on the target hosts and enables me to use the docker module like shown.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)