# How do i pull from insecure docker registry with ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-registry

TLDR; I want ansible to pull a docker image through http not https.

I have two VMs running in the same network.
On one is a local docker registry. The other should pull images from the former via an ansible script. However, I get an error that the registry expects https and is http.

This seemed to solve the problem before. [Ansible task for run Docker container from private registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871016/ansible-task-for-run-docker-container-from-private-registry)

Unfortunateley, ansible docker: is outdated, and I need to use docker_container, and the latter does not have a insecure_registry option.

This is how it looks like now

```
  - name: Run kollega 
    docker_container:
      name: image_name
      image: "ip-to-registry/image:latest"
      ports:
        - "4000:4000"
      restart_policy: unless-stopped
      recreate: yes
      pull: yes
      env:
```

Is there some magic command I can add here to accept http registries, or must I just generate som self-signend certs?

Comment: Ansible does not pull. The target docker daemon does. Configure your registry as insecure: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the target node(s) you are reaching with ansible, add this to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["your-registry:5000"]
}
```

`systemctl restart docker`

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)